# How can I set the spacing option in jq?

Tags: jq

I use `jq` to process json. It outputs pretty-json. How can I customize the amount of spaces when it reformat the file?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently done with the undocumented option `--indent`. I've opened a patch to document it.

- https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/2504/commits/1a4e02e32ece903ae096e860800b447701aaa748

> `--indent` use indent amount of spaces for indentation. between -1 (default of 4 spaces) and 7

Comment: Um... it is documented in release 1.6 ([manual link here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)).  Note that the output of `jq --help` is kept short and only lists the most commonly used options.  There are quite a few options missing in that list, and I believe that this is intentional.